# MySQL/MariaDB Sending additional information with a query

Tags: sql, mysql, mariadb

Let's use this table as an example:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bav6g.png)

To change the status I would do the following:

UPDATE `attribute_values` SET `status` = 'open' WHERE `attribute_values`.`attribute_value_id` = 30315;

Now I would like to send an ID, which normally has nothing to do with this query, but which is required by a trigger.

How can I send something here that will be received by the trigger? Something like additional information when sending a query.

And no, I won't add a column so that I can e.g. B. could send another ID.

I've read through the docs and looked at books, but unfortunately to no avail.

The answers suggested to me are all incorrect, at least not for reasonable use.

A variant that I could now use for my problem would be if I sent every query as a transaction.

So I would first
@userID=123;

Thereafter:

UPDATE attribute_values SET status = 'open' WHERE attribute_values.attribute_value_id = 30315;

And the trigger could intercept the @userID and use it for logging.

Does anyone know of another variant that is also practical for over 100 tables?